# format the echo

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

in my db I am saving the text with html

etc
how can I decode it so that it formats back the text on echo

so if I have this

```
$str = "testing <p>testing 2</p>";
```

it gives something like

```
testing

testing2
```

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are seeing and what you want to see?

Comment: So, you want to keep the `<p>` tags, correct?

Comment: if you want to remove the html, then strip_tags()

Comment: you really want preserve line break?

Comment: Are you asking how to preserve the visual appearance that you'd get when rendering HTML in a browser, but in plaintext? I.e. a paragraph would be displayed with a blank line before and after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you want to see the HTML when displayed in an HTML document. If that is the case, you want

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
// assuming your document is using an UTF-8 charset
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 2):

To simply remove HTML tags from a string using PHP, the [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function will work (and provide options to ignore some tags of your choosing).  If you're asking something else, please clarify what you expect to see / what you're trying and isn't working.