# echo "<?php echo 'Hello' ?>"; It outputs nothing . Is it possible to execute php code in echo . And How can we echo php tags

Tags: php

`echo "<?php echo 'Hello' ?>";` It outputs nothing . Is it possible to execute php code in echo . And How can we echo php tags.

Comment: Why do you need an `echo` inside an `echo` when you can just write `Hello`?

Comment: It outputs. [The code.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/E5K8sV)

Comment: Please be more precise about what you want to know.

Comment: PHP is a server side scriptlanguage. With an "echo" you output it to the Client. He doesn't understand PHP.

Comment: @Pekka He wants to output the string `"<?php echo 'Hello' ?>"`.

Comment: @xdazz are you sure, seeing as he is asking about "executing" PHP code?

Comment: I think he wants to generate some PHP code with PHP and wants to output and execute the generatet PHP code.

Comment: @Pekka if echo doesn't understand php then why its not outputting a php tag as <?php echo 'Hello' ?>

Comment: @Mehul it is  - look into your browser's source code view

Comment: possible duplicate of [format the echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903869/format-the-echo)

Answer (score 6):

Try using [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) to make sure it outputs properly to your browser:

```
echo htmlentities("<?php echo 'Hello' ?>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use '&lt;' instead of < sign and '&gt;' instead of > sign

echo "&lt;?php echo 'Hello' ?&gt;";

Answer (score 0):

It's outputing, but browser just not displaying it.

Try

```
echo "<xmp><?php echo 'Hello' ?></xmp>";
```